# Clarification needed:Projection Or Whole Length to be considered during integration

Tags: electromagnetism, newtonian-mechanics, vectors

Sometimes in magnetism,electrostatics,friction problems when a force is acting over a curved we usually take the net projection of the curved path as the distance(to avoid integration).But it certain problems we take the entire length of the curved path when the force is normal throughout.Why is this so?How to understand when to take projection and when to take the whole length?

For example:Say in this problem why are we taking the whole length after integrating $dl$ vector.Why don't we take projection on x-axis/y-axis?
[image]

But say in this problem we take projection.Why?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoiding integration is not physics. And that isn't what is going on.

What is happening is you are doing the integration, and you are integrating vectors. Sometimes all the vectors point in the same direction so you can add then up like numbers to get the overall vector.

Other times you get a bunch of vectors to add up and they point in different directions. If that happens you can project all those vectors in the x direction and add them up and get the x component. And you can also project all those vectors in the y direction and add them up and get the y component. Similarly for z.

In that second case sometimes one of those projections or two up them give you zero ... after you added up (integrated) the vectors. If someone doesn't show that it might look like they just projected for now reason.

In your first case ask yourself whether the force on each little bit pointed into the page. And if they all point that way so does the sum (the integral). But you could project that vector onto the directions in the paper (and get zero) and then add them all up (and get zero) for those components.

In your second case ask yourself whether the force on each little bit pointed in the plane. Then you could project that vector onto direction into the paper (and get zero) and then add them all up (and get zero) for that component. And then for the components in the plane you can pick two directions. For each direction you can project the force (get something nonzero) then add them up (and if you picked the right direction one of them will be zero).

Some people are very experienced and can figure out the direction the final answer points and just start by computing that and not nothing to project the other directions. Other people are almost as experienced and can see when a calculation is going to give zero and then don't bother doing it. It's like when you integrate $\int_{-1}^{+1}xdx,$ some people can tell it will be zero and might just compute $\int_{-1}^{+1}x^2dx,$ instead of $\int_{-1}^{+1}x+x^2dx,$  because they knew the part they didn't even write down was going to give zero.

You are looking at solutions where someone has that experience. People are integrating. The projection is how you handle vectors that you are integrating because you need to add up all the x components to get the x component of the sum (integral) and this requires a projection. Similarly for y and z.

So in short you projected in both cases, the thing you projected was the force due to a little bit of wire and you did integrate them in both cases.